# How to read cucumber table in a list (column) instead of row

Tags: ruby, cucumber

In Cucumber feature, we could use a table to collect data as below

```
    Then I receive the following errors
        | 10 |
        | 11 |
        | 12 |
```

Then my steps as below.

```
Then(/I receive the following errors$/) do |table|
  data = table.raw
  data.each do |entry|
    status = entry[0]
      # : Do whatever I like
  end
end
```

However, given it's just a list of data, I plan to put it in such feature format instead

```
    Then I receive the following errors
        | 10 | 11 | 12 |
```

I don't know how long the list would be. How should my step definition written to iterate through the table-list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution, which could cater for both row and column.

```
data = table.raw
data.each do |rowdata|
  rowdata.each do |entry|
    status = entry
      # : Do whatever I like
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a comma delimeted list.
Then I receive the following errors

```
"""
10, 11, 12, 14
"""
```

with this code

```
Then(^I recieve the following error$) |errors|
  list = errors.split(/,\s/)
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. This will work as well. I like the table format though as that looks more aligned, and without the need of triple double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for converting `DataTable` with one column to a list of values.

```
Then I receive the following errors
  | 10 |
  | 11 |
  | 12 |

Then(/^I receive the following errors$/) do |table|

    expected = table.cells_rows.map {|row| row(0)} # => [10, 11, 12]

    # do assertions ...
end
```

`cells_rows` will return collection of rows(of type `Cells`), where cells can be accessed by index.  In case with one column index will be always `0`